# Is there a way to center a TideSDK window in the screen?

Tags: tidesdk

When working with TideSDK windows, you get to control their position within the screen. However, I can't find any way to retrieve the screen's size nor a way to center the window.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the user's screen size with `window.screen.width` and `window.screen.height`. You can use those to center a window:

```js
var app_window = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
app_window.setX((window.screen.width-app_window.getWidth())/2);
app_window.setY((window.screen.height-app_window.getHeight())/2);
```

Note that the `window` object here is not an instance of `Ti.UI.UserWindow` but the usual browser `window` object.